# Text under a picture, I want it invisible but I want to be able to find it

Tags: css, html

If I have a picture with sea on it.
I have many pictures in my web page and I want to be able to find this particular picture with Ctrl-f + "sea".

```
<div>
<img src=... alt="sea"/>
</div>
```

I thought about putting text under the picture and using "visibility:hidden;" in the style attribute.
But the problem is that I can't find the picture with Ctrl-f.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

In order to works with any background, you must use transparent color:

```
<div>
<img src=... alt="sea"/>
<span style="color:transparent;">your text</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Trimax/cVdmc/

Comment: Just set display none on the span...wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

Set the text color to match the background color that it's sitting on.  So, if your background is #FFF, set your text color to #FFF.
It will appear, and be searchable, and be selectable, but effectively invisible to the user, unless they know where to look for it.

```
<div>
<img src=... alt="sea"/>
<span style="color:#FFF">your text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was asking myself about a way like visibility:hidden exists or not. What can we do if we have not only one color in the background ?

Comment: An alternate solution would be to put it into a DIV and make the DIV size 0x0.  Or, set the LEFT attribut to -100px.  Either way, it would still render and just not be visible.  Using hidden, hides it too mcuh for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by easy Hack.In any browser you have luxury of option 'Don't load image'.
enable that feature and then search in the browser.

'alt' attribute of img tag will show the text when image file is not loaded.

Comment: The idea was to be able to look for text when seeing images.